# Can I show a child UserControl from a parent UserControl, using the ShowDialog method?

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

I am trying to call the `ShowDialog()` method for a child user control from a parent user control.

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: If the dialog/popup will only be holding your `UserControl` then you can fairly easily dynamically create a `Form` instance to hold it, setting `Dock` to `Fill` for your control, etc.  However, you should probably add more detail to what specifically (and maybe why) you are trying to accomplish to get a more accurate answer.

Comment: Hi, i am trying to use ShowDialog instead of usercontrol.show().

Answer (score 0):

`ShowDialog()` method can only be used on `Form` objects

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.showdialog(v=vs.110).aspx